# Toggle between true or false in setonclick in a item in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, boolean

Is it possible to switch between true or false inside of a `setOnClick`?
I add items with a standard value of false (in my database). And if I click on one item in my `RecyclerView` it changes to true, because of this code:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int selectedItems = position;


                    mFirebaseAdapter.getRef(selectedItems).child("checked").setValue(true);

                }
            });
```

Is it possible to also get the value back to false? So everytime I click it will change between false and true.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my code now.

Comment: What issue do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, read `mFirebaseAdapter` as `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` ! I will retract my comment!

Comment: No problem. But do you have a solution for this question of mine? :)

Comment: I do not use the `FirebaseAdapter` but generally I would create a custom class to maintain a local reference to my data. A part of the structure I would (in this case where you need to maintain a boolean value) add a boolean value. Where the click occurs simple toggle that value and make the necessary changes to the list as needed.

Comment: why don't you retrieve the stored boolean, then set the opposite value?

Comment: @TWL Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events. You can use the single value listener to perform the flip one at a time independently, or the value event listener to maintain a read on your values as you toggle them.